# convert explode results to array in key, value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, explode

I have data like

`list=7251270233&total_amount=28841.28&r_g_amount=1800&cash=1000&credit=500&bank=300&bank_from=abc&bank_to=pqr`

convert it in `array` using `explode` and get a result like

```
0:"list=7251270233"
1:"total_amount=28841.28"
2:"r_g_amount=1800"
3:"cash=1000"
4:"credit=500"
5:"bank=300"
6:"bank_from=abc"
7:"bank_to=pqr"
```

Now I convert it into array in `key->value` like:

```
array("list"=>"7251270233",
"total_amount"=>"28841.28",
"r_g_amount"=>"1800",
"cash"=>"1000",
"credit"=>"500",
"bank"=>"300",
"bank_from"=>"abc",
"bank_to"=>"pqr")
```

so how can I convert in array

Comment: using parse_str() function you can easily convert a query string to a array. As i have done in my answer. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
<?php
$string = "list=7251270233&total_amount=28841.28&r_g_amount=1800&cash=1000&credit=500&bank=300&bank_from=abc&bank_to=pqr";

$info = explode("&",$string);
$result = array();
foreach ($info as $val) {
    $sub = explode("=",$val);
    $result[$sub[0]] = $sub[1];
}

echo "<pre>".print_r($result,1)."</pre>";
?>
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [list] => 7251270233
    [total_amount] => 28841.28
    [r_g_amount] => 1800
    [cash] => 1000
    [credit] => 500
    [bank] => 300
    [bank_from] => abc
    [bank_to] => pqr
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Its is very simple to convert this to an array using [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.phphttp://)

And do like below:

```
 $query_string = "list=7251270233&total_amount=28841.28&r_g_amount=1800&cash=1000&credit=500&bank=300&bank_from=abc&bank_to=pqr";

 $data_array = parse_str($query_string, $output);

print_r($output);
```

The output will be like:

```
Array
(
    [list] => 7251270233
    [total_amount] => 28841.28
    [r_g_amount] => 1800
    [cash] => 1000
    [credit] => 500
    [bank] => 300
    [bank_from] => abc
    [bank_to] => pqr
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$str = 'list=7251270233&total_amount=28841.28&r_g_amount=1800&cash=1000&credit=500&bank=300&bank_from=abc&bank_to=pqr';
$strarr = explode('&',$str);
print_r($strarr);
foreach($strarr as $stra){
    $result[explode('=',$stra)[0]] = explode('=',$stra)[1];
}

print_r($result);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [list] => 7251270233
    [total_amount] => 28841.28
    [r_g_amount] => 1800
    [cash] => 1000
    [credit] => 500
    [bank] => 300
    [bank_from] => abc
    [bank_to] => pqr
)
```

https://eval.in/788202